# Using FlashVars with Flex 3

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, flex3

I'm trying to pass parameters from HTML-land to Flex-3 Flash-land, and can't seem to get it to work. Here's what I've got (basically the default template, modified with FlashVars):

```
<noscript>
<object classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000"
        id="${application}" width="${width}" height="${height}"
        codebase="http://fpdownload.macromedia.com/get/flashplayer/current/swflash.cab">
        <param name="movie" value="${swf}.swf" />
        <param name="quality" value="high" />
        <param name="bgcolor" value="${bgcolor}" />
        <param name="allowScriptAccess" value="sameDomain" />

    <param name="flashVars" value="userID=foo&assignmentID=1"/>


        <embed src="${swf}.swf" quality="high" bgcolor="${bgcolor}"
            width="${width}" height="${height}" name="${application}" align="middle"
            play="true"
            loop="false"
            quality="high"
            allowScriptAccess="sameDomain"
            type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
            pluginspage="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer"
           flashVars="userID=foo&assignmentID=1">
        </embed>
</object>
</noscript>
```

And here's the ActionScript (called after the app's `creationComplete` event is fired):

```
function initApp() : void
{
    // default params
    userID = Application.application.parameters.userID;
    assignmentID = Application.application.parameters.assignmentID;
    if (userID == null || assignmentID == null)
    {
        Alert.show("I didn't get any params!", "Error");
    }
}
```

Anybody know what's going wrong? I've tried several permutations of this with no luck. (Firefox 3, OS-X, Flash Player 9 FWIW)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want to be setting query params after the .swf stuff too. Try

```
 <embed src="${swf}.swf?userID=foo" quality="high" bgcolor="${bgcolor}"
```

Comment: Yep, that's it .. I was modifying the seldom-used "no javascript" version.

http://elromdesign.com/blog/2009/02/17/passing-flashvars-using-flex-template-html/

Answer (score 0):

Try "FlashVars" instead of "flashVars".